# Rails Source Code - why wrapping class inside a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading rails source code, and I can see in some code, instead of using the class directly, it's creating a sub-class. Example code:

```
# activesupport/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb
class RunHook < Struct.new(:hook) # :nodoc:
  def before(target)
    hook_state = target.send(:hook_state)
    hook_state[hook] = hook.run
  end
end


# railties/lib/rails/application.rb
def initialize
  # some code..
  @executor          = Class.new(ActiveSupport::Executor)
  @reloader          = Class.new(ActiveSupport::Reloader)
  # some more code
end
```

My questions is.. why it's needed use a subclass? Why not just use the class / struct directly?

Thanks.

Update: I've figured out the reason for the second example, it's because that `ActiveSupport::Executor` defines `inherited` methdod:

```
class << self # :nodoc:
  attr_accessor :active
end

def self.inherited(other) # :nodoc:
  super
  other.active = Concurrent::Hash.new
end
```

so whoever extends the class, would have `active` attribute defined with a new `Concurrent::Hash`.

However, I still don't quite understand why `Struct` needs to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

Because it has influence on performance and its logicaly different types. `RunHook` has extended functionality. There is no need to call `def before(target)` in all cases where basic `Struct` is used. So here is written a new class with specific method which will be used in specific situations where this method will be needed. And basic `Struct` can be used in all other general situations where is no need for a specific type with the additional functionality.

Also its an architectural and design question about arranging code. Its easier to maintain program if code is correctly splited beetween classes. 
There are five basic principles of object-oriented programming and design: [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Accordingly to [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) principle: "many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface".

Comment: but the Struct.new can take in a block which defines method needed. Why not just use it that way? Docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Struct.html

Comment: It can. But every time when you will need `before` method you will have to pass to the `new` this block of code. And what will happen if `before` is needed  in different parts of your project? What you will do? Will you copy and paste the initialization with the block? Sure! No problem! ...but if something will changed in the future, for example: you need to add one more parameter to yours `Struct.new`. Now you must change code in all parts of your project. So more time needed  to extend functionality or refactor.

Comment: That's why specific class is useful: all changes can be done in one place. Don't repeat yourself [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: I think you should read book ["Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby"](http://www.poodr.com/)

Comment: Yeah I know SOLID but I think it's not related to that. What do u think it's the difference between: 'class RunHook < Struct.new(:hook)' vs. 'RunHook = Struct.new(:hook)'? What I'm asking is.. why use the first one, instead of the second one?

Comment: `class RunHook < Struct.new(:hook)` - definition of class with name `RunHook`.

Comment: `RunHook = Struct.new(:hook)` - creation of the new variable with name `RunHook`

Comment: if u do `C = Struct.new :a, :b, :c`, then `C.class`is actually class, which means, functionally, it has no difference with a normal class (based upon my understanding). So why use the first one, but not the second approach. (You don't really need to answer that.. I'm just trying to clarify my question here). Hope u now agree that this has nothing to do with Design pattern.